# How to prevent JavaScript encoding the query string in a location.replace()?

Tags: javascript, query-string, url-encoding, location-href

I have an already encoded URL string printed in my HTML template via Django. When I place this in a call to location.replace() it gets mangled by some JavaScript that mangles the `=` and `%` already present in the query string, resulting in the subsequent URL (out of my domain) not knowing what to do with it.

How do I prevent JavaScript from changing it?

EDIT:
example url string:

```
'http://destination.com/?name=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&nextparam=nextvalue'
```

passing above into location.replace() results a redirect to:

```
http://destination.com/?name%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fexample.com%252Fnextparam=nextvalue
```

which is obviously incorrect.

The URL has as one of it's query string parameters a URL. The safe encoded characters passed from Django are from the set of characters in the string ':/', basically so the 'http://example.com/' gets encoded correctly. Fine. '=%&' are all untouched parts of the query string.

In my encoded string that works outside of js (eg in anchor tag href) this links to the correct url.

But when I put it in window.location when it redirects it escapes all characters in the query string and removes '&' for some reason - even the '%' used to encode the original URL parameter in the qs. Checking source shows the string is identical to the one in the a tag above.

Is there anyway to prevent javascript location attribute escaping stuff prior to the redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Consider decoding the query string before calling `location.replace()` with it.

You can do this using the built-in [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) function.

Answer (score 1):

You should decode the query string before calling `location.replace()` with it.

<s>JavaScript doesn't have a built in method for encoding/decoding strings, but</s> there is a library called php.js that can help you. [See this link](http://phpjs.org/functions/urldecode:572) for a function for decoding urls. This library is widely supported.

Comment: is there a built-in method for decoding query strings?

Comment: I've expanded on my problem. I only encode some characters prior; others should be left untouched. Sending the url to window.location or location.replace() etc encodes all of the characters prior to redirect for some reason.

Comment: "There is a library for that " is not the same as "That is built in"